# Create Custom validation Class in javaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let say there is an input element field and **i want to create a new validation class** **myClass** ,that i can insert with any html element that might performing some function and also setting attribute such as

```
readonly="true"
required='true'.
```

HTML is

```
<td>
   <input type="text" id="endDate" name ="endDate" class="select_200" required readonly="true">
</td>
```

Now rather setting elements separately need one class for performing:

> A function check `"let say character count less then 10"` and setting
>   attribute.
>
> Setting attributes such as readonly ,required

**So that i can add that class to all elements with similar property.**

> Validation + Setting/ Reseting attributes by adding class only

Comment: Question is not clear what to you wan to achieve.Mention clearly what you want to ask

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own custom attributes for your input elements and use those custom attributes to query the input fields and perform various actions. You can find my sample below.

```js
$(function () {
 //Set various input field attributes here
 $("input[data-myCustomClass]").each(function(){
  //$(this).attr("readonly", true);
  $(this).attr("required", true);
 });

 //Sets max length - you can change this code to retrieve info from attribute
 $("input[data-setFieldLength]").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("maxlength", 10);
 });

 //Validate for field length based on "validateFor" attribute
 $("input[data-validateFieldLength]").each(function(){
  $(this).on('focusout', function(){
    var validateFor = $(this).attr("validateFor");
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length < parseInt(validateFor))
    {
     $(this).focus();
     $(this).select();
    }   
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-myCustomClass data-setFieldLength id="field1" /> 
<input type="text" data-myCustomClasss id="field2" />
<input type="text" data-setFieldLength id="field3" />  <!-- set field length to 10 -->
<input type="text" data-validateFieldLength id="field4" validateFor="5" /> <!-- validate for 5 characters and return focus -->
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i asked .

Comment: can't we have class kind of thing yes that will also work fine buts its not a class.

Answer (score 0):

you have create new function for a field?

Comment: see html element is there i want to create a new validation class that willl set attribute few automatically and also run a  validation method over element where will we addClass class='myClass'

Answer (score 0):

```
      on 
       <form onsubmit="return validate()" name="form">  
       <td>
       <input type="text" id="custname" name ="endDate" class="select_200" 
       required readonly="true">
       <font style="color:red" id="custnameerror"></font>
      </td>
      <button onclick="return validate()"></button>
      </form>

     javascript validation function like
   <script type="text/javascript">


    function validate(from)
     {
    var error=document.getElementById("custnameerror");
    var custname=form["custname"].value;

      error.innerHTML="";

      if( custname==null || custname==""){
          error.innerHTML="Enter customer name";
          return false;
      }

      if(custname.length<3){
          error.innerHTML="Customer name should be minimum 3 character";
          return false;
      } 
      if(custname.length>80){
          error.innerHTML="Customer name should be in between 3 to 80 
      character";
          return false;
      }/*end */

  </script>
```

Comment: where have you added your own defined class, in this code ???
Not a solution read question i am not asking validation entire form !!!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Please try to explain what your code does. Thus other (future) users can also understand the soulution.